# Code in the text control of a grid does not fire

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I try to open a form from a grid on another form. I put my code in the DblClick Event of the Text control in the appropriate column of my grid and yet nothing happens. This works in another app and I cannot see any difference between my two forms. What am I overlooking? Thank you. /bernard

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the text control of the grid and not the grid itself?  Sometimes it is best to use the properties sheet to ensure you are on the grid, to the column to the text control, then the DblClick event.

Comment: Have you used the Debugger to see what's happening? In this case, the Event Tracker would probably be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, DRapp, I am on the text control (I used the Properties sheet). Tamar, here's a copy of the event tracking, it does not even mention the DblClick (??)
42029,376, frmreception.grid_base2.Valid()
42029,376, frmreception.grid_base2.BeforeRowColChange(1)
42029,376, frmreception.grid_base2.column1.text1.RangeLow()
42029,376, frmreception.grid_base2.column1.text1.RangeHigh()
42029,376, frmreception.grid_base2.column1.text1.Valid()
42029,376, frmreception.grid_base2.column1.text1.LostFocus()

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see MouseDown, MouseUp or Click either, I have to assume you're not actually clicking in the textbox or you don't have those methods in the list to be tracked. Here's what I see when I double-click in a grid cell:

```
59739.682, form1.grid1.MouseDown(1, 0, 153, 81)
59739.687, form1.grid1.column2.text1.When()
59739.692, form1.grid1.column2.text1.GotFocus()
59739.692, form1.grid1.column2.text1.Message()
59739.705, form1.grid1.AfterRowColChange(2)
59739.713, form1.grid1.column2.text1.MouseDown(1, 0, 153, 81)
59739.744, form1.grid1.MouseUp(1, 0, 153, 81)
59739.746, form1.grid1.column2.text1.MouseUp(1, 0, 153, 81)
59739.748, form1.grid1.column2.text1.Click()
59739.772, form1.grid1.MouseDown(1, 0, 153, 81)
59739.773, form1.grid1.column2.text1.MouseDown(1, 0, 153, 81)
59739.878, form1.grid1.MouseUp(1, 0, 153, 81)
59739.880, form1.grid1.column2.text1.MouseUp(1, 0, 153, 81)
59739.882, form1.grid1.column2.text1.DblClick()
```

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. When I only list the events appearing on your list they all appear in the same order as in your example but the code still does not fire. 
However, when I list all the events, only the ones listed in my previous message appear in the event tracker.

By the way, here's the code in question:
cNC = THIS.Value
oApp.RunForm('rnc',cNC)

I even deleted my grid and rebuilt it (very carefully) with no result...

Comment: Try adding a DEBUGOUT command to each relevant method and see what you get in the Debug Ouptut window. I'm partial to DEBUGOUT PROGRAM() because it tells me exactly where I am.

Comment: Thank you Tamar. Sorry for the late response (time difference + holiday in France). I added DEBUGOUT PROGRAM() in the method for every event listed in you previous answer and the only result I got was FRMRECEPTION.GRID_BASE2.AFTERROWCOLCHANGE. So, definitely, I do not hit the Text control. All I need to do is figure out why...

Comment: Maybe you've got some setting in the grid that essentially makes the textbox off-limits. Things that might make a difference: the grid's HighlightRow, the column or textbox's ReadOnly and Enabled.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that.

Comment: I've checked all the properties that I could think of. I again compared with my other form on which this works and could not find any difference. I even added a command button on the form to access my method through code (THISFORM.grdGrid.Column1.Text1.DblClick() ). The command is just ignored (I was hoping to get at least an error message). It looks like I will have to find another way to open my form... Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried tracing the code? There's something weird going on here, because what you describe isn't the way this stuff works.

Comment: I have. I placed "SET STEP ON" commands in the Click event of the button and the result is as I described. The cursor gets to the line for the DblClick and when you click for the next step it goes on its merry way but nothing has happened. When I put a SET STEP ON in the DblClick event of my grid I do not even get there. I'm using VFP 8.

Comment: Here's what I get in the Debug Output window when I click on the button:
43632,216, frmreception.nav_command1.MouseMove(0, 0, 67, 254)
43632,763, frmreception.nav_command1.MouseDown(1, 0, 67, 254)
43632,935, frmreception.nav_command1.MouseUp(1, 0, 67, 254)
43632,935, frmreception.nav_command1.Click()
43633,029, frmreception.nav_command1.LostFocus()
43633,045, frmreception.LostFocus()
43633,045, frmreception.Deactivate()
43633,076, frmreception.Paint()
43656,201, frmreception.nav_command1.Valid()
43656,217, frmreception.nav_command1.When()
43661,889, toolbar_nav.Paint()

Answer (score 0):

The reason my code was ignored is that because it was not there. Since I populate the grid with data from another part of the form I have to put in the Init of the grid "THIS.RecordSouce= ...", which means that the grid is "rebuit" and all the PME built in the IDE are gone. Thank you Gregory from AtoutFox. And thank you to all that answered here.
/bernard

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Bernard

I also face the same problem with you. I've been working with VFP9 for years and have no problem working with event Keypress in grid's textbox. Suddenly, by the end of August 2014, all new grids don't respond if we put routine in grid's textbox Keypress event. Strangely, all Keypress event created weeks before, still work well.

I have no idea what cause it. But, fortunately using BindEvent we can solve this problem. And it works well.

Here's the step:

- Create 2 (two) method in your form, say myBindEvent and myKeypress
- After every single line of your code that rebuild the grid source (This.RecordSource="..."), put this code line: THISFORM.myBindEvent
- The routine in myBindEvent:
  LOCAL lnColumn, xz, loRef
  lnColumn = THISFORM.Grid1.COLUMNCOUNT
  FOR xz = 1 TO lnColumn
  loRef = EVALUATE ("THISFORM.Grid1.Column" + ALLTRIM(STR((xz)) + ".Text1")
  BINDEVENT (loRef, "KeyPress", THISFORM, "myKeyPress")
  ENDFOR
- The routine in method myKeyPress
  LPARAMETERS nKeyCode, nShiftAltCtrl

  DO CASE
  CASE THISFORM.Grid1.ACTIVECOLUMN = 1
  IF nKeyCode = 13
      MESSAGEBOX("You press ENTER at Column1.Text1")
  ENDIF

  CASE THISFORM.Grid1.ACTIVECOLUMN = 2
  IF nKeyCode = 13
      MESSAGEBOX("You press ENTER at Column2.Text1")
  ENDIF

  CASE THISFORM.Grid1.ACTIVECOLUMN = 3
  IF nKeyCode = 13
      MESSAGEBOX("You press ENTER at Column3.Text1")
  ENDIF

  OTHERWISE
  IF nKeyCode = 13
      MESSAGEBOX("Why the keypress event no longer work in Grid's textbox?")
  ENDIF

  ENDCASE

Hope this helps.

ps: I got the method BindEvent above from the internet several months ago. But I forget where and who originally wrote that code. If you ever find the original source, the credit goes to him/her.

Regards,

Kusni